# How to list the values from a column the number of times written in the next column?

Tags: vba, list, return

I have in column B some names, and in column C some numbers.

I want in column D to have B printed C times:

```
B : John |  Bob | Steeve 
C :    4 |    0 | 2
D : John | John | John | John | Steeve | Steeve
```

I am currently using in column B the following formula to list the elements of list A that has blanks.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$200,SMALL(IF(LEN($A$2:$A$200)>0,ROW($A$2:$A$200)-ROW($A$200)),ROW(2:2)),1),"")
```

Comment: Try re-writing your question. It literally makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this macro to fill column `D`:

```
Sub FillD()
    Dim colB As Range, b As Range, d As Range, c As Integer
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <-- your sheet's name here
        Set colB = .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        Set d = .Range("D2")
    End With

    For Each b In colB
        c = b.Offset(, 1).Value
        If c > 0 Then
            d.Resize(c, 1).Value = b.Value
            Set d = d.Offset(c)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Works! Thank you much for your help!

Comment: Do you have the possibility to do it on Google sheets by any chance? :/

Comment: @Cook No, I am not familiar with Google sheets, sorry. But you can always ask another question dedicated to porting this code for that ;)